# openni_tracker on OS X

Tags: openi-tracker, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone getting this to work, following the directions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker?

I get the following:

```
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Find user generator failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!
```

This with the unstable branch of perception_pcl on OS X.

Other openni binaries work, like NiViewer.

I have the NI binaries from PrimeSense, but maybe they need to be in a specific location? Or marked in one of my paths?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9575/openni_tracker-on-os-x/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That suggests to me that you have not installed the NITE binaries and registered the plugin with OpenNI correctly.  How did you install OpenNI and NITE?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-04-12**:
Got the binaries, since I can't install from source on OS X. Think I put in the code correctly. How should I have done it?